# PHP Session value not stored on server, works on xampp

Tags: php, session

I'm new here and my knowledge of php is basic, 
I could not find the answer to my problem in other threads, so i hope to find it here.

**situation**:
On local pc (xampp) everything works fine, on webserver i have some problems:

session values created on login are working fine,
session value created while browsing does not get stored.

These sessions created on login are working fine, i can access them on every page:

```
SQL query 
....
 $_SESSION['user_id']= $row['user_id'];
 $_SESSION['user_name']= $row['user_name'];
 $_SESSION['user_pwd']= $row['user_pwd'];
 header("location: overzciht.php");
 exit();
```

This session 'sid' created while browsing has no value on server:

```
<?php
include 'includes/header.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['id'])){
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
   $_SESSION['sid'] = $id;
} else {
  $id = $_SESSION['sid'];
}
....
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $select FROM lijst WHERE id =? ";
$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt -> execute();
```

After a redirect $id is empty,
Accessing `$_SESSION['sid']` on another page does not give any value 
(on server, works perfectly on pc)

`session_start();` is on every page (header.php)
php version in cPanel: native (7.1)

Or should i try a different approach to display the same information for some id. 
( i don't want to have a form with a hidden value for id on every page that redirects).
Thx!

Comment: How is php run (mod-php on apache or fpm)? Check in you php config where the session directory is set to and check if the user that runs php script has write permissions to that directory. Check php error logs, if there are som config issues that prevent from session being written, you should get at least warning messages in the logs

Comment: Server API = CGI/FastCGI ...
session.save_path = /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71.
-> i can't find this path in file manager...
error_log = error_log
-> i can't find an error log....
in cPanel under Metrics: Errors is empty.
in file manager /logs i got 3 files nothing about php.
but sessions from login are working so the /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php71 should be there and working.

Comment: this is a strange issue. If you have session_start on both scripts $_SESSION superglobal should be persistent. Try echoing entire $_SESSION just before redirect and right away after redirect(on receiving script). If the $_SESSION is empty on receiving one then there is a problem with session storage or initialization, if it's empty before redirect or not empy at the start of you receiving script, right after session_start, then there is a problem in your code. At this point there is not much I can help you with

Comment: getting closer, i have a sencond page with same code: if (isset($_POST['id'])){ $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']); $_SESSION['sid'] = $id; }
else { $id = $_SESSION['sid']; }.  if i choose an id on that page, that becomes the session id before redirect. So its a problem in the code. between those two pages. thx for the guiding i'll look in to it tomorrow! confident ill find the solution now.